# How to use transclude on table tr tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have to use transclusion to inject content in a directive, which is applied to a tbody element on the page. I'm trying to apply the transclude onto the tr element of the directive template, but somehow the browser doubles up on the tr elements now - it must auto wrap each td list into a tr before the transclude is running. How can I prevent this from happening?

Please note: I have to make this work as a table in this case, so please refrain from suggestions to replace the table with divs or other elements.

template:

```
<td class="drawer" ng-show="showDrawer">
  DRAWER PLACEHOLDER
</td>
```

including file:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="p in ps
    drawer
    drawer-id="p.ID">
    <td class="p"><span>...</span></td>
    <td class="p"><span>...</span></td>
    ...
></tbody>
```

js:

```
drawer.directive('drawer', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      drawerId: '=' // pass in player id
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: openGlobals.paths.live.drawerTemplate,
    link: function (scope) {
    }
  }
}
```

outcome:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="p in ps
    drawer
    drawer-id="p.ID">
    <tr ng-transclude>
        <tr ng-scope>
            <td class="p"><span>...</span></td>
            <td class="p"><span>...</span></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How did this happen? Why are there two  tags nested within each other?

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: you have `tr` both in your directive template and invocation - not very surprising to get inlined `tr`s. plunkr or fiddle would definitely help you to get a better answer.

Comment: Don't think there is a tr in the directive template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using ng-transclude doesn't seem to work well in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048996/using-ng-transclude-doesnt-seem-to-work-well-in-a-table)