# Angular ng-transclude scope in repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started to study AngularJS and tries to implement customized table directive with the multiple slots transclude. 
And faced situation that scope not transferred to transclude. There is a lot of solutions in other StackOverflow questions, but all of them works only when in directive template ng-repeat appears for top element, but that is not my case.
At least i can't adopt all that solutions.

Simplified version.
Directive:

```
<span>
  <div>Some pagination</div>
  <div style="display: inline"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"/></div>
  <div style="display: inline">Some filters</div>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="line in lines" ng-transclude="row">
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div>Some pagination again</div>
</span>
```

Using of directive:

```
<my-table>
     <row>
          <td>{{line.col1}}</td>
          <td>{{line.col2}}</td>
      </row>
</my-table>
```

Full example with the script on Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rg43ZdPMGHLBJCTLOoLC

Any advice very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and probably cleanest way to directly reference the `$scope` object created by the `ng-repeat` in a transcluded template is through the `$parent` property:

```
<my-table>
  <td>{{$parent.line.col1}}</td>
  <td>{{$parent.line.col2}}</td>
</my-table>
```

The `$parent` property of the `$scope` created for a transcluded template points to the `$scope` of the target template into which such template is ultimately transcluded (in this case, the `ng-repeat`), even though such transcluded `$scope` is not a child of the target $scope in the usual sense as a result of the transclusion. See [this wonderful blog post](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html) for a more complete discussion of this.

Working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/LoqIMiQVZKlTt5epDnZF?p=preview.

Comment: Do you know why instead of td tags angular insert `<span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
      testCol1
      testCol2
    </span>` ?

Comment: yeah, it has to do with the browser registering invalid html prior to the transclusion (as far as I can tell). This is an issue having to do with transcluding `<td>` elements more generally. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048996/using-ng-transclude-doesnt-seem-to-work-well-in-a-table for potential work around

Comment: Note that the `ng-binding` and `ng-scope` "classes" are just normal angular-internal housekeeping. My comment above is a about the <span> element coercion you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $transclude function manually and create new child scope for each line. Other than that you need to pass lines to directive if you are using isolated scope (and you are using it).
Your linking function should look something like this:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude) {
      var tbody = $element.find('tbody');

      $scope.$watch('lines', function (lines) {
        tbody.empty();

        lines.forEach(function (line) {
          var childScope = $scope.$new();
          childScope.line = line;

          $transclude(childScope, function (content) {
            tbody.append('<tr>');
            tbody.append(content);
            tbody.append('</tr>');
          }, null,  'row');
        });
      });
    }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MLNZOmoQyMazgIpluMqO?p=preview

But that is bad idea anyway, cos it is hard to create table this way. As you can see child of  is  not  elements. You would have to do a little bit of DOM manipulation to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is there is a way to take scope of exact element. In my real directive i have additional values fetched from external api and they are  not in topmost directive scope

Comment: Can you please make one more tip for this solution - how to force this newly added elements to use bootstrap style. It not take style at all now.

Answer (score 0):

i see you don't really need to use attribute

so code look more simple and clean:

```
 <body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
   <h1>Table test</h1>
   <my-table lines="lines"></my-table>
 </body>
```

your template:

```
    <span>
      <div>Some pagination</div>
      <div style="display: inline"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"/></div>
      <div style="display: inline">Some filters</div>

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="line in lines">
               <td>{{line.col1}}</td>
               <td>{{line.col2}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div>Some pagination again</div>
    </span>
```

and angular directive:

```
   angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive("myTable", function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          lines:'=lines',
          api: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "template.html",
      };
    })
    .controller("tableCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.lines = [
        {col1: "testCol1", col2: "testCol2"},
        {col1: "testCol11", col2: "testCol21"}
        ];
    }]);
```

working example in plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/iMxRoD0N3sUXqmViHAQh?p=preview

Comment: This solution not helps me, because lines array in fact fetched by paginator and placed in scope of element, so i don't have it outside directive.